# IE8 and overflow

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with IE8, when put a div with "overflow: auto" only is displayed the vertical scroll but no the horizontal.

```
<div class="pnct" style="margin-right: 10px; height: 400px; overflow: auto">
```

Any suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you've set the height, but not set the width.

The div doesnt know at what point to overflow...

Heres a fiddle with the width set and some content.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jvz9E/

Comment: No, because, if I set a default width, happens the same.

Comment: Then your content is not long enough to triggle the need for overflow. The fiddle is a work example proving it works.